# How can I convert a URL string with product numbers into a product name

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

Ok... this is probably an easy question to some of you guys/girls and I know it can be done I just don't know how to make it happen. I think It's done with .htaccess but I'm not too sure. 
I have a site that uses PHP and it has a URL string of:

```
 mydomain.com/product/item.php?=0210
```

How can I convert that item number into the actual product such as:

```
 mydomain.com/product/brown-green-socks
```

Is this possible? If so could you point me in the right direction. I tried to search the site but couldn't find exactly what the process is called so, I really couldn't find the correct answer to my question.

Comment: Are you currently storing the slugs in the database? You'll need to make a map of product IDs to URL slugs, otherwise you'll struggle when handling products with the same name...

Comment: Do you mean that the user should be redirected from ?=0210 to /product/borwn-green-socks?

Comment: You mean you want to [redirect using `.htaccess`](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html)?

Comment: i think mod rewrite should suffice

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina thanks for your time! I was provided the answer below.

Comment: @berkes thanks for your time! I was provided the answer below.

Comment: @BenM thanks for your time! I was provided the answer below.

Comment: @Olical thanks for your time! I was provided the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed URL scheme would require unique product names.

Most larger shops use a scheme like `domain.com/product/0210-brown-green-socks`. That way it's much easier to use [mod_rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) to simply internally redirect requests to that URL to `/item.php?=0210`.

Comment: THANKS! that's exactly what I was looking for the examples they show are precisely the same scenario. I knew it was simple concept I just couldn't get the grip around what it was called. Thanks!

Comment: @codeonfire Glad I could help :-) Don't forget to accept when it let's you.

Comment: i upvoted your question, because it addresses an important issue :D

Answer (score 1):

mydomain.com/product/item.php?=0210 ->301-> mydomain.com/product/brown-green-socks

mydomain.com/product/brown-green-socks means mydomain.com/product/item.php?=0210
They are 2 different things, you'll need 2 rules:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} regex-condition
RewriteRule ^blog/read/(.*)$ blog/index.php?b=$1 [L,QSA]

The first will 301 (moved permanently) redirect to the pretty url. The second will allow your application to understand the pretty url.

Whenever you change the url scheme for a site you should take care of existing links. As such, that first rule is required/a good idea. You should not, however, need the first rule when using your own application. If your own application is generating links to profile.php?user=me - change your application code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question, one is how to identify each element by a 'slug' rather than an id, and the other is how to remove the question mark.

To remove the question mark, try using an apache rewrite in your .htaccess file.  (Google apache rewrites) For example, I use

```
RewriteRule ^blog/read/(.*)$ blog/index.php?b=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So anyone going to blog/read/13 will actually be redirected to blog/index.php?b=13

The next bit would be to start using a 'slug' rather than 'id' when it comes to finding the product in the database.  I could go into more detail but I don't know how your database or website works, so can't help! Thanks